# Mac OS: Where to save NSData object with bookmark of file url?

Tags: xcode, macos, save, nsdata

I'm new to Mac OS development, so I have simple question. I have a `NSURL` object of a folder, I want to keep this URL and make it bulletproof to app quit/reboot/folder rename. So, I made a `NSData` bookmark. I'm a little confuse right now, where I must save this `NSData` object for future use.

It is better to save object to `NSUserDefaults`?

Or I must make a file in my bundle and store this object in it, if so, what must be an extension of that file, and is it "safe"?

Or I must save that file in Application Support Directory ?

After I write this question, I found another one, what if I will have more data to save like `NSString` objects or `NSNumber` or else, I must make another files with info, or could make a one file with all that necessary info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is used to store user preference and other data that will be used by application in the next run. For your instance you can use it.

Application bundle usually not used for writing data. Specifically user may be standard user in that case he/she will have only read,execute permission to App bundle and attempt writing inside bundle will fail.

Application Support directory is used to save files and other big data that application needs in the next run .If data size is less then it is preferred to store in `NSUserDefaults`.

You can define your own keys to save other  `NSString`, `NSNumber` etc objects to  `NSUserDefaults`. Same keys is used to read from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: So, from your answer, I understood, that I could and this will be okay, to store my `NSData` bookmark object of `NSURL` to `NSUserDefaults`, right?

Comment: Thats correct, user preference , user settings, application states are stored in `NSUserDefaults` in general.